# Getting form values of same form using twig

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm adding a confirm details dialogue to a form before it gets submitted, using a bootstrap modal.

The form inputs look as follows:

```
<input type="email" ... name="email" id="email" value="{{ submitted.email }}"/>
```

I'd like to add a line of text to the modal body which reads something like:
"Send to foo@bar.com?"

I tried the these:

```
<p>Send to {{ form.email.get('value') }}</p>
<p>Send to {{ form.vars.value.email }}</p>
<p>Send to {{ submitted.email }}</p>
```

The modal is inside the form which has the input i.o.w:

```
<form method="post" ...>
    ...
    <input type="email" ..../>
    ...
    <button type="button" data-target="thisModal" data-toggle="modal"> Open Modal </button>
    <div id="thisModal" class="modal"...>
         ...
         <div class="modal-body>
             <p>Send to {{ XXXXXXX }}</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit"> Send </button>
         </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Using all 3 prior methods it was simply an empty string, is it possible to grab those values in this way, if so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I did this once but I used jQuery/javascript to show the values in the modal. Just add a class or id via attrs in the form and then load the values in the modal on click.

Comment: Thanks :) I had though of using JS but am curious as to whether there is a way to do it using twig as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal is being called via JavaScript so it doesn't hit PHP at the point wherein which the data needs to be transferred. Hence it cannot be done using twig, as the data is yet to be passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle submitted form data in twig in this way:

```
{{ YOUR_FORM_VARIABLE.FORM_VARIABLE.vars.value }}
```

Do not forget to handle form request in your controller, after submitting data.

For sample:

```
// Some controller
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // supposing that FormType has only email field
    $form = $this->createForm(FormType::class, null, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('homepage'),
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('Bundle:Homepage:layout.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

And in template:

```
// Bundle:Homepage:layout.html.twig
{{ form(form) }}
<b>{{ dump(form.email.vars.value )}}</b>
```

Comment: I think you somewhat misunderstood but thanks for the clear answer :)